# Variables and allocation inside of a loop

Tags: c, memory-management, compiler-construction, memory-leaks

Recently I stumbled upon source code where programmer declared variables inside one infinite loop depending on *if/else* conditions. What I found odd is that the code ran and it didn't implied any memory leaks. First I thought that maybe it was architecture specific thing (the code was for ARM) but I ran some tests and I found out that binaries on IA32 compiled with GCC acted in same way.

My approach was like this: I've created two small program foo.c and bar.c

Foo.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int i;

   for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
      char buf[10];
      buf[i] = 0;
      printf("buf[%d] (@ %#x) == %d\n", i, &buf, buf[i]);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Bar.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int i;

   for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
      char *ptr;
      ptr = (char *) malloc(10);
      ptr[i] = 0;
      printf("buf[%d] (@ %#x) == %d\n", i, &ptr, ptr[i]);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

The reason behind making explicit distinction between declaring an array in *Foo.c* and allocating memory in *Bar.c* was that first I thought that maybe compiler auto-magically detects that it's the same variable and just ignoring the declaration after initial *for* iteration which of course shouldn't be the case in *Bar.c* because I explicitly allocate the memory.

What was really weird to me that in both examples the address of both an array and allocated memory stays the same after initial *for* iteration.

I do not completely understand that and I don't have my copy of *K&R* with me so I'll be thankful for an explanation. (Also if I made any mistake in my reasoning I'd be glad for pointing it out.)

Comment: C++ is different language from C, don't ya know? And `return` ain't a function...

Comment: Tak, wiem. A czy Ty wiesz, ze to zachowanie jest na pewno zwiazane z kompilatorem i jestem prawie pewien, ze G++ zachowa sie tutaj tak samo. Wiec tag C++ nie powinien zostac usuniety IMO.

Comment: First, it's English site, so write in English only; the fact I'm from Poland doesn't change a thing. Second, you are writing in C, not in C++, so C++ tag is irrelevant here.

Comment: @andy, please write in English.

Comment: Tag C++ is relevant because many people who writes in C++ also wrote in C which enables them to help me with my question.

Comment: If they wanted to answer C questions they'd subscribe to the C tag. Using inappropriate tags to get more attention to your question is considered rude.

Comment: @Andy: no. C and C++ are different languages. And you should not cast malloc()s return value, and you should `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: No, a lot of people who write both "C++" and "C" write *bad, sometimes invalid* code in both. They actually only know a horrid mix of the two known as "C/C++"; and vice versa. And most of those people don't know memory management well enough to answer this question well. There certainly are people good at both (possibly even many) but those will watch for both tags independently, and making unclear which one you talk about does not help them answering your question.

Comment: @wildplasser: "you should not cast malloc()s return value" good one, eot.

Comment: @andy In C, you needn't cast, and it's bad style. In C++, you have to (but should rarely use `malloc` anyway). Different languages. _Very_ different.

Comment: I'm puzzled as to the question you are asking.

Comment: I am puzzled, too, but your bar program leaks memory by not having a free that corresponds to each malloc.  If you found code like that in a real program, it is real trouble, eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Don't print the address of your pointer `ptr` (which is a constant inside your loop, since `ptr` is a local variable, in the current call frame), but print the pointer itself:

```
 printf ("buf[%d] == %d, ptr == %p\n", i, ptr[i], (void*) ptr);
```

(remember that if `a` is an array, you do have `&a == a` and their types are compatible, but if `p` is a pointer, you usually don't have `&p == p`, and their types are incompatible)

Of course, if you `malloc` some pointer inside a loop, you usually want to `free` that pointer at the end of the body of the loop.

You should learn to compile with `gcc -Wall -g` (on Linux, perhaps even also with `-Wextra`) and to use the debugger `gdb` (on Linux).

[valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is a useful tool on Linux to catch memory leaks. You could use [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) to "avoid" them (by using `GC_malloc` instead of `malloc`, and not bothering for `free`-ing explicitly memory).

Comment: To be honest, it should be `gcc -Wall -Wextra`, because `-Wall` is in reality `-Wnot-all` (and it's sometimes handy to use `-Werror`).

Comment: It doesn't matter if I do &ptr or ptr because that's irrelevant to the question that I asked. Why? because even if I print out ptr instead of &ptr then still I got the base address the same. I'm asking why it's the same when I'm explicitly allocating memory with malloc in each iteration. Also freeing is pointless in this example (because I *WANT* to make a memory leak).

Comment: @Griwes `-Wall` includes most *generally useful* warnings though, a lot enabled by `-Wextra` is subjective or tries to guess at best practices.

Comment: @delnan, not really, you can easily miss important warnings when not using -Wextra.

Comment: @Griwes Examples please? I recall getting mostly useless ones when using it, but perhaps I don't make the mistakes it catches.

Comment: @andy If you get the same addresses in the `malloc` loop if you print out `ptr` (the address of the `malloc`ed memory), your compiler does something it can't do in real code, eliminate all but the first call to `malloc`.

Comment: @andy, coding `ptr`  is not the same as `&ptr`, so you are mistaken when saying: "It doesn't matter if I do `&ptr` or `ptr` "

Comment: One of the errors tha -Wall does not catch is not casting arguments to varargs functions, like in the above answer.

Comment: Basile, mind casting `ptr` to `(void *)` for printing? Strictly, that's the only type allowed for `%p`.

Comment: @Daniel: Added the `(void*)`  cast for `printf`  with `%p` format

Comment: @delnan Examples for `-Wextra` (from the manpage): missing `return` statement (more or less *always* an error), signed/unsigned comparisons (not always an error, but can hide nasty ones), missing field initialiser (almost always an error).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks, those are indeed useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
    char *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(10);
    ptr[i] = 0;
    printf("buf[%d] ptr is %#x, &ptr is %#x, ptr[i] is %d\n", i, ptr, &ptr, ptr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I added ptr to the output of your bar.c. Now you can find the answer. Here is new source code bar.c. I fixed all the bugs other people mentioned. You can compile it by "gcc -o bar bar.c" and run "./bar".

The output is:

```
    ./bar
    buf[0] ptr is 0x820a008, &ptr is 0xbfb9dc48, ptr[i] is 0
    buf[1] ptr is 0x820a018, &ptr is 0xbfb9dc48, ptr[i] is 0
    buf[2] ptr is 0x820a028, &ptr is 0xbfb9dc48, ptr[i] is 0
    buf[3] ptr is 0x820a038, &ptr is 0xbfb9dc48, ptr[i] is 0
    buf[4] ptr is 0x820a048, &ptr is 0xbfb9dc48, ptr[i] is 0
    buf[5] ptr is 0x820a058, &ptr is 0xbfb9dc48, ptr[i] is 0
    buf[6] ptr is 0x820a068, &ptr is 0xbfb9dc48, ptr[i] is 0
    buf[7] ptr is 0x820a078, &ptr is 0xbfb9dc48, ptr[i] is 0
    buf[8] ptr is 0x820a088, &ptr is 0xbfb9dc48, ptr[i] is 0
    buf[9] ptr is 0x820a098, &ptr is 0xbfb9dc48, ptr[i] is 0
```

You can find the value of ptr changes at every line, but the value of &ptr keeps the same value. 
Conclusion: The ptr allocates different memory at every "for" iteration, but the address of ptr does not change.